# increment number displayed in a div after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to create a rating system. The idea is on page load I would see how many stars each star has. And when I click on the a star it increases the width of the bar. Here is what I am doing. The problems so far are 1: the bars are not displaying correctly 2: the numbers of stars are not incremental correctly. The idea is to update the bar after a new click. Here is the fiddle. I have few other questions associated with this. I will do a new post once I solve this one

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/VU3LP/37/

the Jquery looks like this

```
$(function(){

    var baractive = $('<div class="barActive"></div');
    baractive.appendTo('.bar');

    var curr_val = $('.reading').html();
    var new_val = parseInt(curr_val)+1;

    if(curr_val< 20){
        $('.barActive').css('height', '20px').css('width', '20px');
    }
    if(curr_val< 40){
        $('.barActive').css('height', '20px').css('width', '40px');
    }

    $('.star').click(function(){
        $('.reading').eq($(this).index('.star')).html(new_val); 

        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.bar').eq($(this).index('.star')).addClass('barActive');

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as problem #2 goes: you need to read `curr_val` and compute `new_val` inside the click response function. As it is, you read the first one and use that for all star bars.

As far as problem #1 goes: I have no answer; you say that the bars don't display correctly, but you don't say what behavior you want. However, I suspect that this problem will also go away if you move the css assignments into the click function as well (using `new_val` instead of `curr_val` for the bar). You would still need to initialize each bar using its specific value and index.

Comment: @Ted--I updated the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/VU3LP/40/
I also fixed the number incremental problem. What I meant about the bars is when the page loads it should apply the css property based on the current value. I posted modified the question and posted as a new question here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995701/show-bars-corresponding-to-the-initial-values