# show bars corresponding to the initial values

Tags: javascript, jquery

what am I doing wrong? I am trying to show bars corresponding to the initial values of the class="likes"

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/VU3LP/40/

The Jquery looks like this

```
var baractive = $('<div class="barActive"></div');
    baractive.appendTo('.bar');

    function checkNumber() {
        var valueCurrent = parseInt($(".likes").text());

        if(isNaN(valueCurrent) || valueCurrent <= 20) {
            $(".barActive").css('height', '20px').css('width', '30px').css('background', 'green');
        }
        if(isNaN(valueCurrent) || valueCurrent <= 60) {
            $(".barActive").css('height', '20px').css('width', '80px').css('background', 'green');
        }
    }
    checkNumber();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop in the `checkNumber()` function, so that it will check the value of each `.likes` element and update the corresponding bar.

```
function checkNumber() {
    $(".likes").each(function () {
        var valueCurrent = parseInt($(this).text());

        if (isNaN(valueCurrent) || valueCurrent <= 20) {
            $(this).prev(".bar").children(".barActive").css('height', '20px').css('width', '30px').css('background', 'green');
        } else if (isNaN(valueCurrent) || valueCurrent <= 60) {
            $(this).prev(".bar").children(".barActive").css('height', '20px').css('width', '80px').css('background', 'green');
        }
    });
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/VU3LP/44/)

Comment: The only problem with this is that it is not able to get the conditions correctly. All the bars are showing as same width
Klaster_1 solution works pretty good for this

Comment: I used `else if` for the second value condition, now I think it works correctly.

Comment: Yes it does indeed. Thanks for doing this

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `var valueCurrent = parseInt($(".likes").text());` parses text of all like combined, with result being 2010402060, which is probably not what you want.

I'd change checkNumber function this way:

```
function checkNumber() {
    var bars = $(".bar"),
        likes = $(".likes");

    likes.each(function (index, like) {
        var value = parseInt($(like).text(), 10),
            bar = bars.eq(index).find(".barActive");

        if (value <= 60) bar.css("width", 80);
        if (value <= 20) bar.css("width", 30);
    });
}
```

...and move barActive styles into CSS. [Working example at jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/VU3LP/48/)